# Did Hashem originally intend to have a connection with everyone?

Tags: sources-mekorot, gentiles, theology, creation, abraham

Does it say anywhere that when Hashem created the world it was with the intention to have a connection with everyone, but because people sinned Hashem saw he could only have this intimate connection with Avraham's descendants?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes - every child of Adam HaRishon was supposed to be equal. [At the end of Paragraph #3 in Chap 4 of Part II](https://www.sefaria.org/Derech_Hashem%2C_Part_Two%2C_On_Israel_and_the_Nations.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) in Luzzato's Derech Hashem, he says Hashem judged humanity at the Tower of Bavel - when Avraham was 48. Because Avraham was the only human on Earth who was still working on himself spiritually at that time (he was still living in hiding by Noach and Shem), only Avraham and his children (and all those who will jump onto his "tree") can attain perfection prior to the sin of Adam HaRishon.

> ח"ב פרק ד' אות ב' - אדם הראשון קודם חטאו היה במצב עליון מאד ממה שהוא האדם עתה... ומדריגת האנושיות לפי המצב ההוא היתה מדריגה נכבדת מאד ראויה למעלה רמה נצחיות כמו״ש ואלו לא היה חוטא היה משתלם ומתעלה עוד עילוי על עילוי... והנה בחטאו ירד מאד ממדריגתו ונכלל מן החשך והעכירות שיעור גדול וכמש״ל וכלל המין האנושי ירד ממדריגתו ועמד במדריגה שפלה מאד בלתי ראויה למעלה הרמה הנצחיית שהתעתד לה בראשונה ולא נשאר מזומן ומוכן אלא למדריגה פחותה ממנה פחיתות רב.
>
> שם אות ג' - ואמנם נמצאו כלם לפי המשפט העליון ראוים לישאר במדריגת האנושית השפלה שהגיעו לה אדה״ר ותולדותיו מפני החטא ולא גבוהים מזה כלל ואברהם לבדו נבחר במעשיו ונתעלה ונקבע להיות אילן מעולה ויקר כפי מציאות האנושית במדריגתו העליונה וניתן לו להוציא ענפיו כפי חקו.